# 14.04 & 15.04 usoft Wireless Keyboard doesn't work, Mouse does work

Tags: wireless, keyboard, mouse, microsoft

The Microsoft Wireless Keyboard and Mouse 800.
The mouse works but the keyboard does not.

- lsusb lists the dongle.
- Problem exists on a10/msi desktop with Kubuntu 14.04.
- Problem exists on a10/asus laptop with Kubuntu 15.04.

On the laptop, dmesg says:

```
[ 2715.955041] hid-generic 0003:045E:0745.0002: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Microsoft Microsoft® 2.4GHz Transceiver v8.0] on usb-0000:00:12.0-1/input0
```

None of the wireless keyboards listed in System Settings work.
The 800 is not listed.
Web search shows the 800 works with 12.04 and earlier.
I found no problems like this for 13.04 and later.

What log can I check to dig deeper?  Does someone know the solution?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ooops.  Check the batteries.

Principle:  If an appliance fails, check if it is plugged in.  On batteries, check the batteries.

My keyboard batteries faded out between the grub screen (they worked)
and the login to Kubuntu (they stopped working).

New batteries fixed things.  So I owe those who end up here:

1. These keyboards are not secure.  There is a simple Arduino keylogger.
   I use my keyboard on a HTPC so it doesn't really matter.  Who cares
   what I watch?
2. Some people have had difficulty.  Here are the best discussions I
   found.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/390959

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1546149